# Woocommerce - Append custom field after price in content-single-product.php

Tags: hook, woocommerce

I need to append a custom field called **unit_description** after the price so it would read e.g. $7.00 **per sandwich**.

I'm thinking it would begin with:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_format', 'overwrite_woocommerce_price_format', 10, 2 );

function overwrite_woocommerce_price_format( $format, $currency_pos ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'product' ) return $format;
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'unit_description', true );   // This will return your custom field value
    return $format . ' ' . __( $custom_field, 'woocommerce' );  // Here you'll append your custom field with price
}
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Great! Thanks for confirming